# Kotlin keeps producing error for null exception

Tags: java, android, kotlin

The window .kt file used to add the const array to the layout + some textlayouts and buttons + onclick listener. Its the basic quiz like layout 1 image 4 textviews 1 button.
I tried to do everything but the same error keeps appearing dont know how to fix it.The app works fine on the first page on the app but when i go to this one its instantly closes and throws a
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference

```
package com.example.quizviolence

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.graphics.Typeface
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.ProgressBar
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat

class QuizQuestions : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener {
    private var mCurrentPos: Int = 1
    private var mQuestionsList: ArrayList<Question>?= null
    private var mSelectedOptionPos: Int = 0

    private val progress1:TextView get()= findViewById(R.id.tv_progress)
    private val progressBar1:ProgressBar get() = findViewById(R.id.progressBar)
    private val question1:TextView get()= findViewById(R.id.tv_question)
    private val textView1:TextView get()= findViewById(R.id.tv_option_one)
    private val textView2:TextView get()= findViewById(R.id.tv_option_two)
    private val textView3:TextView get()= findViewById(R.id.tv_option_three)
    private val textView4:TextView get()= findViewById(R.id.tv_option_four)
    private var image1:ImageView= findViewById(R.id.iv_image)

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz_questions)

        mQuestionsList = Consts.getQuestions()
        setQuestion()
        textView1.setOnClickListener(this)
        textView2.setOnClickListener(this)
        textView3.setOnClickListener(this)
        textView4.setOnClickListener(this)
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    private fun setQuestion() {
        mCurrentPos=1
        val questionListNew= mQuestionsList!![mCurrentPos-1]
        defaultOptionView()
        progressBar1.progress = mCurrentPos
        progress1.text = "$mCurrentPos" + "/" + progressBar1.max
        question1.text = questionListNew.question
        image1.setImageResource(questionListNew.image)
        textView1.text = questionListNew.optionOne
        textView2.text = questionListNew.optionTwo
        textView3.text = questionListNew.optionThree
        textView4.text = questionListNew.optionFour
        mCurrentPos += 1
    }
    private fun defaultOptionView(){
        val options=ArrayList<TextView>()
        options.add(0,textView1)
        options.add(1,textView2)
        options.add(2,textView3)
        options.add(3,textView4)

        for (option in options){
            option.setTextColor(0xFF7A8089.toInt())
            option.typeface= Typeface.DEFAULT
            option.background=ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,R.drawable.default_option_boarder_bg)
        }
    }

    override fun onClick(p0: View?) {
          when (p0?.id){
                 textView1.id -> {
                     selectedOptionView(textView1, 1)
                 }
              textView2.id -> {
                     selectedOptionView(textView2, 2)
                 }
              textView3.id -> {
                     selectedOptionView(textView3, 3)
                 }
              textView4.id -> {
                     selectedOptionView(textView4, 4)
                 }
          }
    }
    private fun selectedOptionView(tv: TextView,selectedOptionNumber:Int)  {
        defaultOptionView()
        mSelectedOptionPos= selectedOptionNumber
        tv.setTextColor(0xFF363A43.toInt())
        tv.setTypeface(tv.typeface,Typeface.BOLD)
        tv.background=ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,R.drawable.selected_option_boarder_bg)
    }
}
```

Comment: `private var image1:ImageView= findViewById(R.id.iv_image)` – That's calling `findViewById()` immediately during field initialization, which is too early. Did you mean to declare that a `val` with a `get()` function, like the others?

Comment: @MikeM. im calling it from my xml file 
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_image"
            android:layout_width="278dp"
            android:layout_height="118dp"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_bg" /> is it wrong?

Comment: Nothing to do with that. Compare the `private var image1:ImageView` line to the lines for the `TextView`s and such above. Those others are declared `val` not `var`, and their `findViewById()` calls are actually in their `get()` functions, not directly assigned to the variables. I would guess that you actually meant `private val image1: ImageView get() = findViewById(R.id.iv_image)`, unless you plan on reassigning `image1` later on somewhere.

Comment: @MikeM. i found the problem :) you were right they were intitialized too early (and i wanted to use var not val it got changed while i was trying stuff) i used lateinit and now everything works perfectly. Thank you